# How to JOIN with similar columns?

Tags: sql, join

If I have two tables A and B, so that table A has columns: ID, VALUE, ACTIVE
and table B has columns: ID, NAME, ACTIVE.

A.ACTIVE and B.ACTIVE refer to different things.

Upon 
SELECT * FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID

I would like to seperate the ACTIVE column so that I know which is which.
How do I go about accomplishing that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use * and qualify each column

```
select a.active as a_active, b.active as b_active, ... 
  from a join b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Is there a way to go about this with the asterisk ?

Comment: You could technically still use a.*, b.*, ... but it's generally good practice to qualify all the columns you will be using anyways.

Comment: @Ted No: There is no way to use a.*, b.* - you must name each column then give it an alias as required

Comment: Depending on which database he's using, he technically can... although still in agreement that he should just qualify each column.

Answer (score 1):

> A.ACTIVE and B.ACTIVE refer to different things

I think you should re-evaluate your naming convention. Consider that columns from the domain of `ACTIVE`values should have distinct names for each occurrence (column) in the schema (tables) e.g. as a first step try qualifying them by prefixing with the table name... but first consider more meaningful names than `A` and `B` :)

As per @dispake's answer, you can use `AS` clauses to rename the columns 'on the fly' but this should be regarded as a code smell if you need to do it frequently.